# Getting fixture not found error in allure report

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

Trying to run following test using pytest but getting below error.
fixture 'result_type' not found.

```
@allure.step("Generating Test Results")
def testResultPngToPdf(result_type):
'''Function call to make pdf for all screen shots taken during execution'''
logging.info(f"Total Screenshots captured : {len(screenshots_list)}")
logging.info(f"Result type value  : {result_type}")
screenshots_list[-1] = pass_fail_watermark(result_type, screenshots_list[-1])
pdf_filename = ("TestResults/"+scenario_to_run+"_" +current_time+"_"+result_type+".pdf")
screenshots_list[0].save(pdf_filename, "PDF", resolution=100.0,
                        save_all=True, append_images=screenshots_list[1:])
screenshots_list.clear()
```

Please find below error:

```
@allure.step("Generating Test Results")
def testResultPngToPdf(result_type):
E       fixture 'result_type' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```